# mark and unMark box in uitableview cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view like a below picture:

I want to change check box and use mark check box when I select a table row in section Absence

I know that I should use this method didSelectRowAtIndexPath: "that when user select the row it should change the picture "
but I don't know how

would you please help me

Thanks in Advance!

here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if (indexPath.section != 2) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text =contentForThisRow;
    return cell;
}
else {
    CheckBoxCompensationViewCell *cell = (CheckBoxCompensationViewCell*)[tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CheckBoxCompensationViewCell"];

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheck-box.png"];
    cell.checkBox.image = image;
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.compensationText.text =@"Red";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.compensationText.text =@"Green";

    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.compensationText.text =@"Blue";
    }
    return cell;
}
}



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// I don't know what should I have here , probably mark box image but I don't know how
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *previousPath = self.selectedIndexPath;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[previousPath, indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

note this is very basic, and wont deselect a cell, and you will need to check the state of the selected index path in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: 12 thanks but do you know how can I have limitation of just one choose

Comment: you need to have a property which indicates which indexPath is currently selected, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy. When user select cell, you should update your data model and reload table. Data model stores the buttons status.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath method do setup buttons according to data model state. That's all.